# write/save an array of custom objects android java

Tags: java, android, serialization

I have been using this code:

```
                 public void saveCredits(int myInt) {
         try {
            OutputStream fos = openFileOutput("test.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            DataOutputStream dis = new DataOutputStream(fos);
            dis.writeInt(myInt);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
         }
         catch (IOException e) {
             System.out.println(e); 
         }
      }
```

How do I modify it in the simplest way to also write an array of custom objects such as houses(String name, int cost, Address address)

Comment: Do you also have code that reads it in? Why not use serialization? It's a little more to learn but you will save in the long run http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way with DataOutputStream is to:

1. store array size
2. then items themselves

Like this:

```
DataOutputStream out = ... ;
out.writeInt(items.length);
for (Item item : items) {
    out.writeUTF(item.someString());
    out.writeFloat(item.someFloat());
}
```

Loading such an array is easy too:

```
DataInputStream in = ... ;
int length = in.readInt();
Item[] items = new Item[length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    items.add(new Item(in.readUTF(), in.readFloat()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **ObjectOutPutStream** and method **writeObject()**.. Preciseley you need to **Serialize and Deserialize** your Objects.. [more here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)